# How to rewrite Rule in apache for wordpress json API v1 and v2

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress-json-api

I'm trying to develop a vuejs frontend site with wordpress as headless CMS.

so far everything is fine, but one thing worries me.

the frontend is served at domain.com/index.html so I renamed the wordpress root document index.php to _index.php. For reading the /wp-json/v2/ API I added

```
RewriteRule ^wp-json/(.*) /_index.php [L]
```

to the apache .htaccess file to redirect the call.

However, if I now also want to call the old json API with ?json=, the

```
RewriteRule ?json(*) /_index.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^?json=(.*) /_index.php [L]
```

does not work.

how can I use both APIs, no idea why the rewriteRule doesn't work.

this is how mine looks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^wp-json/(.*) /_index.php [L]
   #RewriteRule ^?json(*) /_index.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

by the way: is there a way with the json API V2 to output the pages recursively as Parent/Child tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I renamed the wordpress root document `index.php` to `_index.php`

Why? If you are having issues with `index.php` taking priority when requesting the root directory then reset the `DirectoryIndex`. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Now, only `index.html` will be checked for when requesting a directory. (It was probably set to something like `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` previously, so `index.php` would take priority.)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^?json=(.*) /_index.php [L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match the query string you need to use a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^json=
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

The regex `^$` ensures that only requests for the document root are matched and not any URL-path.

`^json=` matches any query string that *starts* `json=`. The `(.*)` part is not required. The `QUERY_STRING` server variable does not include the `?` delimiter itself.

NB: The regex `?json(*)` (in your first example) is not valid and you'd expect to get a 500 response (if on Apache), since the regex would fail to compile.

The `/` prefix on the *substitution* string is not required and should be avoided. (This now makes use of the `RewriteBase` directive - which isn't actually required here anyway.)

So, in summary, it would look like this, with a few minor tweaks:

```
# Limit the directory index to "index.html" only
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Pass Authorization header to backend on CGI
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Stop early if the front-controllers are already reached
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php)$ - [L]

# WordPress API
RewriteRule ^wp-json/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^json=
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

# VueJS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: if I call the json api v2 in wordpress from a local website via fetch, it works without any problems. 

when I call the old json api via fetch I get an error unable to fetch (directly with the browser no problem) 

in the network debug tab I see
provisional headers are shown Learn more
application/json: application/json
DNT: 1
Referrer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.7

What could be the reason.

Comment: "when I call the old json api via fetch" - What are the URLs/endpoints for these APIs?